# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre &arr+1 y arr+1?

Tags: c

Ambas expresiones `&arr+1`y `arr+1` no dan el mismo resultado y esto se lo comprueba con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int arr[] = {40, 41, 42, 43};
    int* ptr = &arr+1;
    int*ptr2 = arr + 1;
    printf("%d, %d\n", *(ptr-1), *ptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado por pantalla es:

```
43,41
```

La pregunta del millón: ¿Por que en `*(ptr-1)` dio como resultado `43`?

Porqué esta claro que `*ptr2` da como resultado un `41`, debido a que, tiene la dirección de memoria del segundo elemento del arreglo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ¿Cual es la diferencia entre &arr+1 y arr+1?

El problema es que, aunque tanto `arr` como `&arr` se refieren a la misma dirección, sin embargo ***no son del mismo tipo***.

- `arr` es de tipo *"dirección de int"*, pues equivale a poner `&arr[0]` y en `arr[0]` hay un entero, por lo que `arr` es una dirección de un entero.
- En cambio `&arr` es de tipo *"dirección de array de 4 int"*, pues efectivamente lo que hay en la dirección de `arr` es un array de 4 enteros.

La diferencia en el tipo afecta a la *aritmética de punteros* que es en cuánto se incrementa realmente cuando se le suma 1.

Si tienes un puntero a un `tipo` cualquiera, y sumas 1 al puntero, en realidad se sumará `sizeof(tipo)`, para así apuntar al siguiente elemento de ese mismo tipo. Por tanto:

- `arr+1`, ya que como hemos visto `arr` apunta a un entero, sumará en realidad `sizeof(int)`, que son habitualmente 4 bytes. Por tanto `ptr2` en tu código apuntará a una posición que está 4 bytes después del comienzo del array. Así pues apuntará al siguiente entero.
- `&arr+1`, ya que como hemos visto `&arr` apunta a un array de 4 enteros, sumará en realidad `sizeof(arr)`, que en este caso es `4*sizeof(int)`, y serán por tanto 16 bytes (asumiendo que `sizeof(int)` es 4). Así pues quedaría apuntando a un hipotético array de cuatro enteros que iría después de `arr`, aunque no tienes tal cosa en el programa. El puntero `ptr` por tanto está mal asignado y de hecho no coinciden los tipos pues declaraste `ptr` como puntero a `int`, pero le asignas un puntero a array de 4 ints. Tendrás un *warning* en esa línea.

Todo lo anterior se demuestra con este programa:

```
int main()
{
   int arr[] = {40, 41, 42, 43};
   int *ptr = &arr+1;
   int *ptr2 = arr + 1;

   printf("%p %p\n", &arr, arr);
   printf("%p %p\n", ptr, ptr2);

}
```

La cadena de formato `%p` suele usarse para volcar valores de punteros. En realidad simplemente vuelcan en hexadecimal la dirección en cuestión. En el primer `printf()` volcamos la dirección de `arr` y la de `&arr`, para comprobar que ambas son iguales. En el segundo `printf()` volcamos los valores de los punteros para comprobar que el primero se ha incrementado en 16 y el segundo en 4, con respecto a la dirección del array.

La ejecución produce:

```
0x7ffeeb0ad900 0x7ffeeb0ad900
0x7ffeeb0ad910 0x7ffeeb0ad904
```

que coincide con lo esperado (recuerda que 10 hexadecimal es 16)

> ¿Por que en `*(ptr-1)` dio como resultado 43?

Porque debido a que has declarado `ptr` como de tipo puntero a `int`, la artimética de punteros `ptr-1` le restará en realidad `sizeof(int)`, o sea 4 bytes. Recordemos que según se explicó antes `ptr` apuntaba 16 bytes más allá del comienzo de `arr`, es decir, a la primera posición "fuera" de ese array. Al restarle 1 al puntero (4 bytes a la dirección) queda apuntando al último elemento de `arr`.